# Android project display error on R.id.button

Tags: android

I surdenly noticed that My project starts throwing error anytime I try to access a resources that is a button. It underlines R.id.button. I dont understand why. I even deleted the last xml that I created but problem persist.

This is an example of my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/layoutborder"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="@string/stepone"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/wine" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ai" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/drugdetails"
        style="@style/smallButtonStyleBlackpearl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/nextbut" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My Java code

```
package com.example.rhemahealthcare;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.example.rhemahealthcare.R;

public class SteponeActivity extends SherlockActivity{


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.steponeactivity);

        final Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(SteponeActivity.this,SteptwoActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });
    }

}
```

Comment: post your code please

Comment: Do you have `android:id="@+id/button"` in any of your layout xml files?

Comment: Can you please post the xml activity and your Java class?

Comment: I do have id with that format  @AleksG

Comment: check your imports and make sure there is not an import referencing R

Comment: Try cleaning the project also check your imports.

Comment: Try cleaning the project and also check your imports

Comment: I have check import I have tried importing with full path. it not working. It seems that my project is not generating all my buttons. And all xmls are not showing errors

Comment: just to be clear, you dont import android.R; in your java file? if you do you should delete it

Comment: Please I dont know how to paste an xml here. Can some help

Comment: yeah I dont do it. @JockMahon

Comment: Copy the text in the xml file and paste it at the place where you wrote your question.

Comment: I have done that but it complaining of formating @ShobhitPuri

Comment: I have pasted an activity class with it xml. Infact all activities were I used a button is getting an error. But the code above is one of my activity class were I used a button

Comment: Ohh  I think I have seen the error. my ids for no reason just change to button1 in all activities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Aleks G gussed it right in the comment, you don't have any button with id as `button1` in your `xml` file. You've mentioned it :

```
final Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Use the appropriate ID or put one in your layout file.

Comment: yeah, It wasn't like that I dont know how all my class files just have their button ids change. automatically. It a surprise to me. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

i think you change any button1 id buy clicking right click and choose edit id. this option changes all the ids with that name in all the layouts.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the problem. My button ids were automatically change to button1 so they did not reference their previous ids that I gave to them. Thanks alot